# Create a post after user registration in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-hook

I need to create a post after user registration with some roles in wordpress !

i used this code

```
    add_action( 'user_register', 'create_resume', 10, 1 );

function create_resume( $user_id )
{
    // Get user info
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $user_roles = $user_info->roles;

    // New code added 
    $this_user_role = implode(', ', $user_roles );

    if ($this_user_role == 'candidate') {

        // Create a new post
        $user_post = array(
            'post_title'   => $user_info->username,
            'post_status'  => 'publish', // <- here is to publish
            'post_type'    => 'resume', // <- change to your cpt
            'post_author'  => '$Post_id',
        );
        // Insert the post into the database
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $user_post );
    }
}
```

but dosn't work ! :-(

anybody can help me ?

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: NO
but not working to create a post for new users!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'create_resume', 10, 1 );

function create_resume( $user_id )
{
    // Get user info
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $user_roles = $user_info->roles;

    // New code added 

    $has_candidate_role = in_array('candidate', $user_roles);

    if ($has_candidate_role) {

        // Create a new post
        $user_post = array(
            'post_title'   => $user_info->username,
            'post_status'  => 'publish', // <- here is to publish
            'post_type'    => 'resume', // <- change to your cpt
            'post_author'  => $user_id,
        );
        // Insert the post into the database
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $user_post );
    }
}
```

Comment: this code can't create a post after user registration !

Answer (score 0):

i can create the post with this code [after user registration]:

```
add_action('user_register', 'resume_create', 10, 1);
function resume_create($user_id)
{
    // Get user info
    $user_meta = get_userdata($user_name);

    // Create a new post
    $user_post = [
        'post_title' => $_POST['slug'],
        'post_type' => 'resume',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => $post_ID,
    ];
    // Insert the post into the database
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($user_post);
}
```

But, not assign to curent user and special role.